# Изменение цвета шапки при прокрутке страницы

Tags: jquery

Почему класс `stick_r` не удаляется, когда я прокручиваю страницу вверх, но все нормально работает при прокрутке вниз?

Суть кода: Изменение цвета шапки, если я буду прокручивать страницу.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".menu").each(function () {
       var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
       var div_top = $(".menu").offset().top;
        if (window_top > div_top - 400){
            $(".menu").removeClass('stick_r');
            $(".menu").addClass('stick_r');}
        else{
            $(".menu").removeClass('stick_r');
          };
    });
});
```

Comment: не могли-бы вы приложить html код?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wPgXMp

Comment: почему-бы вам не использовать для этого $(".class").css({"background": "your color"});?

Comment: Так тоже не работает. Цвет меняется 1 раз при прокрутке вниз, а при прокрутке вверх не меняется.

Comment: вам нужно,чтобы при прокрутке вверх менялся цвет?а при прокрутке в них на другой?

Comment: Смотрите, я сделал фиксированную шапку, но при прокрутке вниз цвет пунктов меню сливается с фоном, по-этому я должен поменять цвет фона шапки(в данном случае, если я прокручиваю страницу вниз на 400 пикселей, то меняется фон, это работает), но потом когда я прокручиваю страницу в самый верх, этот фон должен стать прежним, как в начале, то-есть прозрачным.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это может помочь:

```
var scrolled;
window.onscroll = function() {
    scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    if(scrolled > 400){
        $(".menu").css({"background": "black"})
    }
    if(400 > scrolled){
        $(".menu").css({"background": "white"})         
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает!